# Setting JLabel Text at Runtime

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, concurrency

I am pretty new to Java(about 2 weeks in), and I am trying to set the text of a JLabel. The only problem is I am doing calculations in another class and I don't know how to reference the Jlabel I have already created. Here are the two classes in question.

```
package fightsim;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class FightSimPane extends JPanel {
FightManager FightManager = new FightManager();
/**
 * Create the panel.
 */
public FightSimPane() {
    setLayout(new MigLayout("", "[][][][][][][][][][]", "[][][][]"));

    JLabel lblChampionleft = new JLabel("ChampionLeft");
    add(lblChampionleft, "cell 1 3");

    JButton btnGo = new JButton("Go");
    btnGo.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            FightManager.startFight();
            FightManager.runTheFight();

        }
    });
    add(btnGo, "cell 5 3");

    JLabel lblChampionright = new JLabel("ChampionRight");
    add(lblChampionright, "cell 9 3");

}


public void setLeftChampionLabel(String s){
    //not able to reference Jlabel lblChampionLeft here???
    System.out.println("Setting Left Champion text to"+s);

}

public void setRightChampionLabel(String s){
    //not able to reference Jlabel lblChampionRight here???
    System.out.println("Setting Right Champion text to"+s);
}


}
```

And the class that is trying to set the Label.

```
package fightsim;

public class FightManager {

Champion LeftChamp = new Champion();
Champion RightChamp = new Champion();

public FightManager() {

}

Thread LeftChampThread = new Thread(LeftChamp);
Thread RightChampThread = new Thread(RightChamp);

;

public void startFight() {

    LeftChamp.setHealth(200);
    RightChamp.setHealth(300);
    LeftChamp.setATKsp(1000);
    RightChamp.setATKsp(1000);
    LeftChamp.setAD(20);
    RightChamp.setAD(20);

}

public void runTheFight() {
    System.out.println("Starting Threads");
    LeftChampThread.start();
    RightChampThread.start();

    while ((LeftChamp.getHealth() > 0) && (RightChamp.getHealth() > 0)) {

        if (RightChamp.isReadyToAttack()) {
            LeftChamp.setHealth(LeftChamp.getHealth() -     RightChamp.getAD());
            RightChamp.setNotReady();
            System.out.println("Setting Left Champion test to"
                    + Integer.toString(LeftChamp.getHealth()));

            // This is where I'd like to update the left Jlabel in
            // FightSimPane

        }
        if (LeftChamp.isReadyToAttack()) {
            RightChamp
                    .setHealth(RightChamp.getHealth() - LeftChamp.getAD());
            LeftChamp.setNotReady();
            System.out.println("Setting Right Champion test to"
                    + Integer.toString(RightChamp.getHealth()));

            // This is where I'd like to update the right Jlabel in
            // FightSimPane
        }

    }

}
}
```

So, the question...How do I let my FightManager Class access and change the JLabel in my FightSimPane Class/Gui. Thanks in advance, and sorry if this is a stupid question. I am terribly new to programming and I'm still trying to take it all in. With that said, any other advice would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Pass references around so that classes can communicate with each other, and not only that but with the correct active instance of the class of the other type.  For instance, you could give FlightManager a FlightSimPane field:

```
class FightManager {

   private FightSimPane fightSimPane;

   // and fill it in the constructor:
   public FightManager(FightSimPane fightSimPane) {
      this.fightSimPane = fightSimPane;
   }
```

Then you'll be dealing with the actual visualized FightSimPane GUI object.

Note that you'll have to take care to pass in the correct instance:

```
public class FightSimPane extends JPanel {
   FightManager FightManager = new FightManager(this);
```

Then you can call the public methods of FightSimPane in the FightManager class:

```
public void runTheFight() {
  System.out.println("Starting Threads");
  LeftChampThread.start();
  RightChampThread.start();

  while ((LeftChamp.getHealth() > 0) && (RightChamp.getHealth() > 0)) {

     if (RightChamp.isReadyToAttack()) {
        LeftChamp.setHealth(LeftChamp.getHealth() - RightChamp.getAD());
        RightChamp.setNotReady();
        System.out.println("Setting Left Champion test to"
              + Integer.toString(LeftChamp.getHealth()));

        // !!!  **** added this *************
        fightSimPane.setRightChampionLabel("Setting Left Champion test to"
              + Integer.toString(LeftChamp.getHealth()));

     }
```

***EDIT 1***
I see another potentially serious and unrelated problem here:

```
  while ((LeftChamp.getHealth() > 0) && (RightChamp.getHealth() > 0)) {

     //.........

  }
```

This code appears to be called on the main Swing thread, the EDT and it's nature (while (true)) suggests that it has a very good chance of locking up the EDT bringing your Swing GUI's graphics processing and updating and all user interactions to a screeching halt. You may need to use a Swing Timer for this or a background thread so as to leave the EDT free to do its necessary work.

Comment: Ok that helps, now my issue is with the setRightChampionLabel(String s) and setLeftChampionLabel(String s) methods. Is there any reason I cant put lblChampionleft.setText(s); in there?

Comment: @ThadBlankenship: Yeah, don't declare the JLabels inside of a method or constructor! That way their visibility is limited to the same method or constructor. Instead declare these guys as a non-static class field and allow it to be visible throughout the class. This has nothing to do with Swing but instead is basic Java variable scope 101.

Comment: Ah, I was using windowbuilder and it declared them in the constructor. Whats up with that?

Comment: @ThadBlankenship: another argument for not using code generators until you are very very familiar with the library.

Comment: I see your point there but at the same time I feel I learn best by looking at code and then climbing the walls myself when I hit them. I got it all working now, and moved the while loop to a separate thread. Works flawlessly. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: @ThadBlankenship: if it's like Eclipse, it will give you the option of creating a local variable, or a class field.

Comment: @ThadBlankenship: glad  you've got it working. It's a nice feeling when something you've built starts to come together and perform magic.  That's the only reason I do this chit. :)

Comment: Yeah it's Eclipse. I'll have to pay more attention to checkboxes when i make windowbuilder components. Thanks for the help, it really does feel like magic. Take care.

Answer (score 1):

Declare the reference variable of `FightSimPane` class in `FightManager` class and pass the reference of `FightSimPane` object via the constructor of `FightManager`.

In FightManager class,

```
public class FightManager {

Champion LeftChamp = new Champion();
Champion RightChamp = new Champion();
private FightSimPane pane;

public FightManager(FightSimPane pane) { this.pane=pane;}
public FightManager() {
}
....
```

Using "pane" reference variable you can access accessible elements of `FightSimPane` class.

Modify the FightSimPane code,

```
public class FightSimPane extends JPanel {
FightManager fightManager;

public FightSimPane() {
     fightManager= new FightManager(this);
     ...
}
```